# AMD A8-4500 APU with Radeon HD 7640g

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, proprietary

I have installed many versions of Linux lately, trying to free myself from windows, I have played with Linux over that past few years, but I was into gaming, and until recently couldn't fully commit to running a Linux laptop.

I for the life of me cannot get my graphics card to work with the AMD drivers to support full 3D, and full performance. The Gallium3D driver gives me slow, and undesirable performance and battery life.

I would like to be running Kubuntu 13.04. withe the amd proprietary driver working. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have exhausted my alternative resources to find my own solution.

My graphics card is the dual graphics that is part of the AMD A8-4500 APU (HD 7640g)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same APU, but in a Desktop.  I'm really not much into gaming, but a friend of mine is, and also an AMD fanatic.  He installed this [Driver](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/hotfix/catalyst_12.6_hotfixes/amd-driver-installer-8.98-x86.x86_64.zip) on my machine, and it works like a charm.  Keep in mind that this is still a beta driver.

Also you can visit this [page](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst126beta.aspx), for fixes, and enchantments that are available in this driver.

Comment: I have already tried this, I am thinking maybe the mobile version acts differently, I have tried all sources I could find on the internet without any success. Thanks for the reply.